# Show/hide md-sidenav by typescript code

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I have a typescript code with his template html

```
 <button md-icon-button (click)="menuSidenav.toggle()">
        <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
    </button>
....
<md-sidenav-container style="height: 100px">
    <md-sidenav align="start" mode="over" #menuSidenav
```

if I click on the button it works but I would like show and hide the sidenav by typescript code

How you do  ?

Thanks a lot beacause I don't know get the element by typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Otherwise this solution works for me in my case in my class component :

```
 @ViewChild("menuSidenav") sideNave: any;
```

and in the code

```
this.sideNave.open();
```

What do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

In Angular, for simple things like hiding and showing template items you don't want to be getting the element directly in typescript. You should be using the built in template directive `ngIf`:

```
<button md-icon-button (click)="menuSidenav.toggle()">
    <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
</button>
....
<md-sidenav-container style="height: 100px">
    <md-sidenav *ngIf="toggled" align="start" mode="over">
```

The `ngIf` directive manages hiding and showing if the argument evaluates as true or false. So by using a boolean field 'toggled' in your component typescript, just like you've used the 'toggle' in the event above:

```
class MyComponent... {
    ...
    public toggled = false;

    toggle() {
      this.toggled = !this.toggled;
    }
```

Documentation: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Answer (score 0):

I got into same issue and this is how I get it fixed.

Instead of using *ngIf, user [ngStyle] and based on your criteria set display to 'block' or 'none'